# font color change for every click using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery in my application.I need to change the font-color of the text enclosed in `<p></p>` tags every time a click is made on the text.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where the next color comes from, so here's an example using a random color each click:

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({ 
        'color': 'rgb('+ (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) +','+ 
                         (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) +','+ 
                         (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) +')'
    }, 500);
});​
```

[You can view a demo of the effect here](http://jsfiddle.net/ezrKj/) :)

If you don't want it to animate like I have, just change [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and the change will be instant, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ezrKj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the tags and then change the css for this tags, e.g. for a `<div id="yourid">`:

```
$('#yourid').click(function() {
    $('#yourid').css('color' : '#yourNewColor');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.It works fine far a single color change ie.,when I make a click on the paragraph,the font-color changes to the new color specified.
But I want the color to be changed every time to some new color when a click is made.

Comment: Then take the functionality of Nick Cravers answer to change the color randomly. Or create an array of colors and a pointer and count up that counter and choose the specified element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this where your tags have a class "tag" and the font-colour is defined by a class called "highlight":-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tag').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
  });
});
```